# adding elements to a numpy array and reshape it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy array

```
a= np.array([1,1])
```

I have the two elements

```
b= [2, 2]
c= [3, 3]
```

I would like to add those elements b and c, so that my output seems like this

```
a= [[1, 1],
    [2, 2].
    [3, 3]], #shape=(3,2)
```

which numpy function should i use?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `numpy` array with the three elements

```
>>> np.array([a,b,c])
array([[1, 1],
   [2, 2],
   [3, 3]])
# shape : (3, 2)
```

If a had more than 1 dimension, `np.append` can be used :

```
>>> a= np.array([[1,1], [4,4]])
>>> a
array([[1, 1],
       [4, 4]])
>>> np.append(a,[b],axis=0)
array([[1, 1],
       [4, 4],
       [2, 2]])
```

Comment: yes this worked fine thanks, but havin two elements in the a array (a= np.array([[1,1], [4,4]])) makes it impossible to add the elements b and c with this solution.
do u have suggestions to solve it ?thnx

Comment: @ABA added an edit with this